# How to solve max min (convex functions)?

Tags: optimization

I am trying to solve the following optimization problem.

$$
\max_{A} \min_{i,j,i\neq j} ||A(x_i-x_j)||_2^2 \\
\text{s.t } ||A||_F^2 <=1
$$

$A$ is a matrix and $x_i$ are given vectors. The min of convex functions is not a convex/concave function. Is there any tricks to convert it to a convex problem or an approximation of a convex problem?

Comment: Is it possible to impose the constraint $\|A(x_i-x_j)\| \geq d$ and then adjust $d$ such that $d = \min\limits_{i,j}\|A(x_i-x_j)\|$ for some $A$?

Comment: $||A(x_i-x_j)|| \geq d$ is not a convex constraint.

Comment: It's important what are the directions of projection for linear operator A, because if this direction coincides with x_i - x_j then min = 0. So, it's worth to transform A to diagonal form by using principle directions.